# RegisterStartupScript error message VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am trying to call JavaScript code from my VB.NET code behind and use the following code:

```
Protected Sub ApplyGridViewPageChangingActions(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles GridView_Body.PageIndexChanged
    Dim oldPageIndex As Integer = Context.Session("GridViewPage")

    If GridView_Body.PageIndex > oldPageIndex Then
        Dim func As String = "ApplyGridViewPageChangingActions('" + Context.Session("LastFundCode") + "', '" + Context.Session("ExpOrColl") + "');"
        Context.Session("GridViewPage") = GridView_Body.PageIndex
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "ApplyGridViewPageChangingActions", func, False)
    End If
End Sub
```

However I am getting this error message:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The script tag registered for type 'ASP.lsc_code_placeorders_aspx' and key 'ApplyGridViewPageChangingActions' has invalid characters outside of the script tags: ApplyGridViewPageChangingActions('baef', '0');. Only properly formatted script tags can be registered.
```

Why is it not properly formatted? ApplyGridViewPageChangingActions('baef', '0'); looks perfectly acceptable to me.

Comment: I changed it to be alert('boo!'), and I get the same error!

Comment: Apparently I have to wrap my call to the function with <script> tags!